# How to render local image path properly in DOMPDF?

Tags: php, phalcon, dompdf

I'm using **DOMPDF** to generate PDFs. I'm trying to add local images into the PDF but the path is not rendering correctly! I'm getting a `space`, `"` and `=` characters extras in the rendered path.

Code:

```
foreach ($routineVideos as $video) {
        $thu = $video["thumbnail"];
        $thumb = '<img src="../uploads/membership/routine-videos-thumbnails/"'. $thu . '/>';
        $html .= $thumb;
        var_dump($html);exit;
}
```

I'm getting the below result:

```
<img src="../uploads/membership/routine-videos-thumbnails/" video_20120719143839.jpg="">
```

What I want is:

```
<img src="../uploads/membership/routine-videos-thumbnails/video_20120719143839.jpg" />
```

And in generated PDF I'm getting `Image not found or type unknown` error instead of image

Comment: Well then put the second `"` in the correct place, instead of placing it _before_  the contents of `$thu` …

Comment: @04FS `$thumb = "<img src='../uploads/membership/routine-videos-thumbnails/$thu'/>";` is working!

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are using phalcon as backend

since you are provided with working solutions
i would suggest using Phalcon url service to maintain consistency
if (uploads/membership/routine-videos-thumbnails) is in your public directory use:

```php
$thumbPath = $this->url->get("uploads/membership/routine-videos-thumbnails/{$thu}");
```

if its not and its within app directory use defined constants and the config service (phalconpath/app/config/config.php)
for example if the (uploads/membership/routine-videos-thumbnails) is in app directory you use:

```php
$thumbPath = APP_PATH . '/uploads/membership/routine-videos-thumbnails/' . $thu;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$result = 'str_'.$var.'_str';` or `$result = "str{$var}str";` with braces.

And do not use single quotes in HTML attributes.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it